# Matlab for loop and if statement simplification

Tags: matlab, loops, simplify

Hello I'm writing function to find a biggest gaps between actions in days. But I wanna simplify for loop and if to a one liner like Lambda in java.

```
function [retObj] = find_gaps (data, n)

[~,n1] = size(data);
dates = 1;
gaps = 1;
for i = 1:n1
  if i > 1
    gap = data(i) - data(i-1);
    dates(end+1) = data(i-1);
    gaps(end+1) = gap;
  end
end
dates(1) = [];
gaps(1) = [];

fprintf('Highest gaps:\n');
for i = 1:n
    [val,key] = max(gaps);
    fprintf('%s gap: %d\n',datestr(dates(key)), val);
    gaps(key) = [];
    dates(key) = [];
end
```

Comment: Oneliners are overrated. Just saying. Not that your code couldn't be made much more efficient.

Comment: Yes maybe the question should be how to make this code more efficient.

Comment: Keywords: pre-allocation (of `dates` and `gaps`), redundancy (loop from `i=2` in your first loop, no if needed then; `dates` and `data` might be the same), vectorization (`gaps=diff(data);` instead of the loop).

Comment: @AndrasDeak IMO vectorization is what often meant by one-liners

Comment: @brainkz then it is often being wrong:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main task here is to find the gap, i.e. the difference between two subsequent entries in `data`. This can be done efficiently with the [`diff`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function: simply call `diff(data)`.

The rest is only about creating the correct output: We have to sort the gaps in a descendant matter, e.g. with the [`sort`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function. Note: we use the second output of `sort` too, which is the index.

```
[gap, ind] = sort(diff(data), 'descend');
```

Next, we create a cell array containing all output (convert all `data` entries to `datestr` and put them into a cell. Add the gap to that cell array. Finally transpose to let all dates be in the first row, and all gaps in the second row):

```
out = [ cellstr(datestr(data(ind).')),
        mat2cell(gap.',ones(1,numel(gap)))
      ].';
```

And let everything run through the `fprintf` function:

```
fprintf('%s gap: %d\n', out{:})
```

Unfortunately not a one-liner, but still it removes all for's and if's. Here's an example:

```
data = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1005, 1006, 1018, 1019, 1021];

[gap, ind] = sort(diff(data), 'descend');
out = [cellstr(datestr(data(ind).')), mat2cell(gap.',ones(1,numel(gap)))].';
fprintf('%s gap: %d\n', out{:})
```

resulting in

```
02-Oct-0002 gap: 12
28-Sep-0002 gap: 3
15-Oct-0002 gap: 2
26-Sep-0002 gap: 1
27-Sep-0002 gap: 1
01-Oct-0002 gap: 1
14-Oct-0002 gap: 1
```